# Kendo UI for Angular align labels in CategoryAxis

Tags: kendo-ui, alignment, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I have a problem with the pdf extraction of Kendo Ui for Angular. I can't manage to align properly the labels of the bar chart in the image.

[labels not align properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSRvS.png)

I tried all the attributes on Kendo documentation but I could not find a solution.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?